# Left specification for integral

Tags: integral

I am trying to reproduce the following formula, where an integral has a “specification” assigned, placed on its bottom left; any idea on the proper/best way to do so?

[image]

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/557655/low-level-command-for-controlling-left-superscript-spacing

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `\sideset` command from `amsmath` is designed for this purpose.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\[
\sideset{_{(\alpha)}}{^{1}_{0}}\int\frac{dQ}{T},\sideset{_{(\beta)}}{^{1}_{0}}\int\frac{dQ}{T},
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: That is perfect!  Thanks a million!

Answer (score 9):

I set the specification as a subscript to a “phantom” integral. Some care is needed to get spacings right. Since the macro ends with `\int`, the limits will be read as usual.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\specint}[1]{%
  \mathop{}% for the spacing before the integral
  {\vphantom{\int}}_{(#1)}%
  \!% remove the spurious spacing
  \int
}

\begin{document}

\[
\specint{\alpha}_0^1\frac{dQ}{T}
\qquad
\specint{\beta}_0^1\frac{dQ}{T}
\]
\begin{center}
% to see what happens inline
$\specint{\alpha}_0^1\frac{dQ}{T}
\qquad
\specint{\beta}_0^1\frac{dQ}{T}$
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

### Comparison with the other proposed solutions

1. `\specint` is my proposal
2. `\sideset` doesn't work inline
3. with `\mathllap` the spacing is weird
4. with `\prescript` the specification sits lower than the lower limit (and there is no `\mathop`)
5. with `\raisebox` the effect is awful as soon as inline math is tried

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[tiny]{titlesec} % spare on vertical spacing

\begin{document}

\section{\texttt{\string\specint}}

\newcommand{\specint}[1]{%
  \mathop{}% for the spacing before the integral
  {\vphantom{\int}}_{(#1)}%
  \!% remove the spurious spacing
  \int
}

\[
\specint{\alpha}_0^1\frac{dQ}{T}
+
\specint{\beta}_0^1\frac{dQ}{T}
\]
\begin{center}
$\specint{\alpha}_0^1\frac{dQ}{T}
+
\specint{\beta}_0^1\frac{dQ}{T}$
\end{center}

\section{\texttt{\string\sideset}}

\[
\sideset{_{(\alpha)}}{^{1}_{0}}\int\frac{dQ}{T}
+
\sideset{_{(\beta)}}{^{1}_{0}}\int\frac{dQ}{T}
\]
\begin{center}
$\sideset{_{(\alpha)}}{^{1}_{0}}\int\frac{dQ}{T}
+
\sideset{_{(\beta)}}{^{1}_{0}}\int\frac{dQ}{T}$
\end{center}

\section{\texttt{\string\mathllap}}

\newcommand\myint[3]{%
   \mkern23mu\int_{\mathllap{(#1)\mkern15mu}#2}^{#3}}

\[
\myint{\alpha}{0}{1} \frac{dQ}{T}
+
\myint{\beta}{0}{1}  \frac{dQ}{T}
\]
\begin{center}
$\myint{\alpha}{0}{1} \frac{dQ}{T}
+
\myint{\beta}{0}{1}  \frac{dQ}{T}$
\end{center}

\newpage

\section{\texttt{\string\prescript}}

\[
\prescript{}{(\alpha)}{\int^1_0}\frac{dQ}{T}
+
\prescript{}{(\beta)}{\int^1_0}\frac{dQ}{T}
\]
\begin{center}
$\prescript{}{(\alpha)}{\int^1_0}\frac{dQ}{T}
+
\prescript{}{(\beta)}{\int^1_0}\frac{dQ}{T}$
\end{center}

\section{\texttt{\string\raisebox}}

\[
\raisebox{-.25cm}{$_{(\alpha)}$} \int_0^1 \frac{dQ}{T}
+
\raisebox{-.25cm}{$_{(\beta)}$} \int_0^1 \frac{dQ}{T}
\]
\begin{center}
$\raisebox{-.25cm}{$_{(\alpha)}$} \int_0^1 \frac{dQ}{T}
+
\raisebox{-.25cm}{$_{(\beta)}$} \int_0^1 \frac{dQ}{T}$
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

Comment: @Rpy For your convenience I added a comparison of the proposed solutions

Comment: Thanks a million—you're too kind! :)

Answer (score 4):

I take it that the prefix term -- `(\alpha)` resp. `(\beta)` -- and the lower limit of integration -- `0` for both integrals considered here -- must share the same baseline. If this assumption is correct, the following solution, which uses the `\mathllap` macro provided by the `mathtools` package (a superset of the `amsmath` package), should be of interest.

It provides a user-level macro called `\myint` (feel free to come up with a different name...) that takes three arguments: the prefix, the lower limit of integration, and the upper limit of integration. The first argument should be non-empty -- otherwise, why bother with using `\myint`? -- while the second and third arguments may be empty.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} % for \mathllap macro
\newcommand\myint[3]{%
   \mkern23mu\int_{\mathllap{(#1)\mkern15mu}#2}^{#3}}

\begin{document}
    
\[
\myint{\alpha}{0}{1} \frac{\mathrm{d}Q}{T}\,,
\quad 
\myint{\beta}{0}{1}  \frac{\mathrm{d}Q}{T}\,.
\]

\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*: As @mbert has pointed out in a comment, the `mathtoools` package provides a macro called `\prescript` that's ideally suited to take care of the job at hand.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} % for '\prescript' macro

\begin{document}
\[
\prescript{}{(\alpha)}{\int^1_0}\frac{\mathrm{d}Q}{T}
\quad
\prescript{}{(\alpha+\beta+\gamma)}{\int^1_0}\frac{\mathrm{d}Q}{T}
\quad\textstyle
\prescript{}{(\alpha+\beta+\gamma)}{\int^1_0}\frac{\mathrm{d}Q}{T}

\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: mathtools also provides a `\prescript` command which seems to produce very similar results

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Try `x+\myint{\alpha+\beta+\gamma}{0}{1}`

Comment: @mbert - Thanks for the suggestion -- I'll post an addendum to show how to use `\prescript` for the job at hand.

Comment: @egreg - Piece of cake with the help of the `\prescript` macro. :-)

Answer (score 3):

Try this code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,adjustbox}

\begin{document}
    
    \[
    \raisebox{-.25cm}{$_{(\alpha)}$} \int_0^1 \frac{\text{dQ}}{\text{T}}, \quad \raisebox{-.25cm}{$_{(\beta)}$} \int_0^1 \frac{\text{dQ}}{\text{T}},
    \]
    
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Just curious: Is there a reason to prefer `\raisebox{-.25cm}{$_{(\alpha)}$}\int` over `\raisebox{-.32cm}{$\scriptstyle(\alpha)$}\int`?

Comment: @Mico estetic taste...

Comment: Thanks for your answer!