# How to write half integrals in LaTeX?

Tags: integral

I would like to know how to write half integrals and generally integrals of nth order in LaTeX, for example in Cauchy's formula for repeated integration, because I didn't find how to do that on the whole internet. Also I attached how I write this on paper.[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.  I'm not familiar with "half integrals", and am not quite sure what you mean by "integrals of nth order".  Could you point us to an example?

Comment: By half integral I mean differintegral of -1/2 order.

Comment: But what does it look like?  How would you write it with a pencil and paper?  Could you point us to an image?

Comment: See this answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/557678/19809

Answer (score 6):

Maybe you're looking for some specific notation that I don't know about, but in LaTeX, Cauchy's formula for repeated integration can for example be written as:

```
I^nf(x) = \int_0^x \int_0^{x_1} \cdots \int_0^{x_{n-1}} f(x_{n}) \, \mathrm{d}x_{n} \cdots \, \mathrm{d}x_2 \, \mathrm{d}x_1 = \frac{1}{(n-1)!} \int_0^x\left(x-t\right)^{n-1} f(t)\,\mathrm{d}t
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.  I don't think this is what OP was looking for, so it would probably be better to wait for OP to clarify.

Comment: Thank you, this is very useful!

Answer (score 6):

Add a phantom integral, so the subscript is at the right place.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\NewDocumentCommand{\INT}{m}{\mathop{{\vphantom{\int}}}\nolimits_{#1}\!\int}

\begin{document}

A displayed integral
\[
\INT{n}_a^b f(x)\,dx
\]
A text style integral $\INT{n}_a^b f(x)\,dx$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Of course codepoint 0x222B in any unicode font, can give you integrals at any size. Do you think unicode-math is mature enough?

Comment: I'm not sure about unicode-math, but your answer was extremely helpful. Thank you a lot!

Comment: And one extra question: where do I put this code: in LaTeX environment or in post when I create a new one or edit an existing one?

Comment: @Taras You just copy the definition in the preamble of your document.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to use also `tensor` package with `\mathclap`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tensor}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\[
\tensor*[_{\mathclap{c}}]{\int}{_a^b} f(x) \ dx
\]
$\tensor*[_{\mathclap{c}}]{\int}{_a^b} f(x) \ dx$
\end{document}
```

[image]